# Distribution of linear model predictions not symettrical?

Tags: regression, linear

I'm training a linear model to predict log(returns) of a given financial series. The shape of my target distribution has about as many returns above 0 as below 0 (top image). My predictions distribution has an R2=0.07 -- I hear this is typical for financial series -- however the distribution skews very differently to the right (bottom image)?

What directions can I take to get a model that has a more balanced distribution?

[image: Top image -- target log(return) of a financial series, bottom image - predictions from my linear model]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It is not clear why you want a symmetric distribution. Is it because your observed median is around zero? (That can happen with skewness.)

Comment: I'm using this to predict returns for a trading strategy. I'd like to be able to go both long and short. If the true returns are symettrical I'd like the predictions to match it primarily so I can get short trades as well that match the actual signal.

In short in my application it's valuable to have both >0 and <0 predictions.

Comment: You can see the observed returns. Is there symetry?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not using the right terminology. I want to get more negative predictions. 

`
Y (the target)  has
 23% < 0 ,  37% == 0,  38% > 0

The predictions are
 15% < 0, 85% > 0 

`

Comment: A couple of more points to consider: (1) Are the target values $y$ rounded somehow? Why are there gaps in the histogram of $y$? (2) You are worried about the skewness of the predicted values, $\hat{y}$, but notice that their spread doesn't look "right" either (the $\hat{y}$s are much closer to 0 than the $y$s).

Comment: Good clarification -- the data is log(returns) for ES futures. The price for ES is quantized to a minimum of $0.25 increments so the target returns 

log(price_at_5_seconds_ahead) - log(price)

Should be quantized.

How do I build a linear model?